# identify the highest `letter` – ignoring B – within `ID` in a longitudinal data set

Tags: r

I am trying to identify the highest `score` within `ID` in a longitudinal data set.

Say my data looks like this,

```
dfL <- data.frame(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L), week = c("baseline", 4L, 6L, "baseline", 6L, 9L, 9L, 12L, "baseline", 4L, 6L, 9L, 12L, "baseline"), score = c(NA, "A", "B", NA, "B", "E", "D", "C", NA, "B", "A", "A", "B", NA)); dfL
   ID     week score
1   1 baseline  <NA>
2   1        4     A
3   1        6     B
4   4 baseline  <NA>
5   4        6     B
6   4        9     E
7   4        9     D
8   4       12     C
9   9 baseline  <NA>
10  9        4     B
11  9        6     A
12  9        9     A
13  9       12     B
14 10 baseline  <NA>
```

What I am looking to do is to find the highest score, expressed in letters, ignoring B's, and placing this letter on the `baseline` for each `ID`. The designed result would look like this,

```
dfL$hi_score <- c("A", NA, NA, "E", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA);dfL
   ID     week score hi_score
1   1 baseline  <NA>        A
2   1        4     A     <NA>
3   1        6     B     <NA>
4   4 baseline  <NA>        E
5   4        6     B     <NA>
6   4        9     E     <NA>
7   4        9     D     <NA>
8   4       12     C     <NA>
9   9 baseline  <NA>        A
10  9        4     B     <NA>
11  9        6     A     <NA>
12  9        9     A     <NA>
13  9       12     B     <NA>
14 10 baseline  <NA>     <NA>
```

For people who know how to solve this, can you recommend any books or webpages that have good tutorials for learning how to manipulate longitudinal data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick solution.

```
dfL <- data.frame(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L), week = c("baseline", 4L, 6L, "baseline", 6L, 9L, 9L, 12L, "baseline", 4L, 6L, 9L, 12L, "baseline"), score = c(NA, "A", "B", NA, "B", "E", "D", "C", NA, "B", "A", "A", "B", NA));

#find the highest score per id excluding "B"
highestScore = by(dfL$score, dfL$ID, function(ids){ 
    head(rev(sort(ids[ids != "B"])), 1) 
})

dfL$hi_score = NA
for (id in names(highestScore)){
    newWeek = as.character(highestScore[[id]])
    #to account for weeks with no scores
    newWeek = ifelse(length(newWeek)==0, NA, newWeek)
    #only update the hi scores at the baseline position  
    dfL[which(dfL$ID == id & dfL$week == "baseline"), "hi_score"] = newWeek
}

dfL
```

As for the tutorials, it's all about practice.  Reading the questions and answers on this site is a great start.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. When I run your solution I get an error on the dummy data saying `Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, dfL$ID == id & dfL$week == "baseline",  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames` is it my R version 2.15.2 or did I overlook something?

Comment: I must have been using a different version of R on my office computer.  I just edited the answer and it it works fine on 2.15.3.  In this new version I make a new hi_score column, instead of overwriting the week column.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does the job.

```
dfL <- data.frame(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L), week = c("baseline", 4L, 6L, "baseline", 6L, 9L, 9L, 12L, "baseline", 4L, 6L, 9L, 12L, "baseline"), score = c(NA, "A", "B", NA, "B", "E", "D", "C", NA, "B", "A", "A", "B", NA)); dfL
library(plyr)

dfL$score <- as.character(dfL$score)
dfL$score <- ifelse(dfL$score!="B",dfL$score,NA)
maxdat <- ddply(dfL,.(ID),summarise,hi_score=max(score,na.rm=TRUE))
finaldat <- merge(dfL, maxdat, by="ID")
```

And if you really want missings in the rows that are different from the baseline week you can do:

```
finaldat$hi_score<- ifelse(finaldat$week=="baseline", finaldat$hi_score,NA)
```

If you want to learn more about data transformation you should certainly check Hadley's packages like `reshape2` http://had.co.nz/reshape/ and `plyr` http://plyr.had.co.nz/.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I like your use of `plyr`, but your solution is not ignoring the B's. If I run your function `ID` 1 and 9 get an B and not an A as it should have. Can this be fixed in an easy way?

Comment: Yes before the ddply statement you can set the B scores to NA. I edited the question